# completely unrelated exception while saving many to many relationship doctrine and php

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

so, I have multiple entities in my app, between them:

Product* - *Order

User* - 1UserRole

Order

```
class Order
{
...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinTable(
     *     name="orders_products",
     *     joinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    private Collection $products;
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...
    public function addProduct(Product $product):self
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Product

```
class Product
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected Collection $orders;
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addOrder(Order $order): self
    {
        $this->orders[] = $order;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

User

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRole")
     * @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $role;
}
```

And UserRole:

```
class UserRole
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true, length=20) */
    protected $name;
    /** @Column(type="integer", unique=true, nullable=false) */
    protected $rolePriority;

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Stores.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserRoleAction", inversedBy="user_role_actions", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected Collection $userRoleActions;

    /**
     * UserRole constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoleActions = new ArrayCollection();
    }
...
}
```

Ok so far, my issue is the following, when I try to save a new order that has many selected products:

```
class OrderService
{
    public function createFromRequest(HttpRequest $request)
    {
        ...
        $products = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->findWhatever(); //products are coming from this without issues.

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $order->addProduct($product);
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($order);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return $order;
    }
}
```

I get:

> Blockquote Expected value of type "UserRole" for association field "User#$role", got "__PHP_Incomplete_Class" instead.

I mean, how is this in any way related with the other entities??? I have no clue where to go to be fair. Any recommendations? Is doctrine doing some absolutely unrelated validation behind the scenes? wth?